# 'stringify_keys' error when trying to use a form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following within a form_for:

```
  = form_for @activity do |f|
    .field
      = label :comment, :comment
      = text_area :comment, :comment, :rows => 4
```

I am not calling f.label or f.text_area because comment is a separate model and I am saving it separately.  The above code works fine, but when the validation fails on @activity, then the comment gets wiped out.  I would like for the comment field to repopulate when the @activity validation fails, so I tried the following:

```
  = form_for @activity do |f|
    .field
      = label :comment, :comment
      = text_area :comment, :comment, :value => @comment, :rows => 4
```

With this line in the controller action:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment][:comment])
```

With this, however, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "hello":String
```

It is failing on the @comment assignment in the controller which I show above.

What is going on here?

The params after the error contain the following:

```
 "comment"=>{"comment"=>"hello"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Comment#new` expects a Hash whose keys correspond to Comment's attributes but you're giving it `params[:comment][:comment]`, whose value is a string (in this case, `"hello"`). I suspect that this is what you want instead:

```
@comment = Comment.new params[:comment]
```

Comment: when I do that, the comment repopulates with "#<Comment:0xc25c25c>"

Comment: sorry, when the validation fails for activity and the form is re-rendered, the comment field has "#<Comment:0xc25c25c>"

Comment: Oh, that's because you have `text_area ..., :value => @comment, ...`, and `@comment` contains a Comment object, not the text of the comment. Try `:value => @comment.comment` (assuming `comment` is the attribute that holds the text of the comment).